# Qt: Why is the background of my image green on LinuxFb?

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux, framebuffer

My Qt application is supposed to display a JPEG image to an HDMI monitor.  When I run the application on my Linux desktop environment, the image is displayed correctly.

However, when I run this application in an embedded Linux environment under LinuxFB, there is a large amount of green surrounding the image.

NTSC (720x480) color bars on my 1080p monitor.

[image]

My application was written with QLabel instead of QWidget, and does not have any active window.  I have attempted a number of solutions, mostly using QPainter, but so far nothing has made a difference to background appearance.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Set the app palette to be transparent
    app.setPalette(QPalette(Qt::transparent));

    QPixmap input ("test.jpg");
    QImage image(input.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);

    // Try to fill the QImage to be transparent
    image.fill(Qt::transparent);

    QPainter p(&image);

    // Try a few things to get the painter background to be transparent
    p.setOpacity(0.5);  // 0 is invisible, 1 is opaque
    p.setBackgroundMode(Qt::TransparentMode);
    p.setBackground(Qt::transparent);
    p.setBrush(Qt::transparent);

    p.drawPixmap(0,0,input);
    p.end();
    QPixmap output = QPixmap::fromImage(image);

    QLabel label (0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);

    // Set the style sheet background color as transparent as well
    label.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;");
    //label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);");

    label.setPixmap(output);
    label.setScaledContents(true);
    label.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The application is executed with the following

```
./my-Qt-application -qws -nomouse -display LinuxFb:/dev/fb1
```

I do not believe this has anything to do with the Linux frame buffer itself because the green background is only present when I am running a Qt application.

Assuming the green background is coming from Qt, what can I do to turn it off (or make it transparent)?

Comment: Thanks, that is a typo.  I corrected it in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Qt 4.8 (probably 4.x)

The green background is coming from [QWSServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwsserver.html). You can change it by using [QWSServer::setBackground()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwsserver.html#setBackground).

#### Qt 5.x

The origin of the green background is still Qt, but `QWSServer` doesn't exist anymore. I'd suggest using a fullscreen `QWidget` as a background. You can change to background color of the `QWidget` with a simple stylesheet containing `background-color: black;`.

Answer (score 0):

You've done nothing to scale the label properly. The green background is where your label isn't - it's probably the default contents of the framebuffer. Fill the entire screen and you won't have that problem.